# How to synchronize ctr and ai channels reading using NIDAQmx API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nidaqmx

I have a chassis cDAQ-9174 and two DAQ (NI 9421 and NI9208), that I am using to monitor some voltage based sensors and reading some frequency based sensors.

For this, in MATLAB, I created a session where I added ai_channels for the voltage based sensors and ci_channels for the frequency sensors. I even managed to make a buffered aquisition so I can get 1 Hz frequency synchronized readings:

"Matlab Code"

```
s = daq.createSession('ni'); 
addAnalogInputChannel(s,'cDAQ3Mod3','ai2','Voltage');
addCounterInputChannel(s,'cDAQ3Mod2', 'ctr0', 'Frequency');
addCounterInputChannel(s,'cDAQ3Mod2', 'ctr1', 'Frequency');
% addCounterInputChannel(s,'cDAQ3Mod2', 'ctr2', 'Frequency');
% addCounterInputChannel(s,'cDAQ3Mod2', 'ctr3', 'Frequency'); 

s.DurationInSeconds=5; %Tempo de aquisição
s.Rate=1; %Number of samples per second
% inputSingleScan(s)

[data,time]=s.startForeground();
```

Since Matlab licenses are a bit expensive and python is not, I was converting this code to python (v3.7) using the NIDAQmx library.

I was very disappointed to find out that, apparently, you cannot add different channel types to the same task:

```
import nidaqmx as daq

fTask = daq.Task()
fTask.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("/cDAQ3Mod1/ai8")
fTask.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("/cDAQ3Mod1/ai0")
ftask.ci_channels.add_ci_freq_chan("cDAQ3Mod2/ctr0")

nidaqmx.errors.DaqError: Task cannot contain a channel with the specified channel type, because the task already contains channels with a different channel type.

Status Code: -200559
```

Looking into the documentation for this error you will find:

Error -200559
Task cannot contain a channel with the specified channel type, because the 
task already contains channels with a different channel type. Create one 
task for each channel type.

So, right now I am puzzled that the MATLAB code works (and it does) and how can I implement two tasks that have synchronized aquired data.